# Modal view not working for angular2 and ng2-bs3-modal

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use angular2 RC5 with ng2-bs3-modal.
My problem is that the modal view doesn't appear and the object this.modal is undefined when I'm trying to open the modal.

These is my source code

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MODAL_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MODAL_DIRECTIVES, ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [MODAL_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
        <modal #myModal>
            <modal-header [show-close]="false">
        <h4 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h4>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-body>
        Hello World!
    </modal-body>
    <modal-footer [show-default-buttons]="true"></modal-footer>
        </modal>
    `

})
export class AppComponent { 
@ViewChild('myModal')
    modal: ModalComponent;

    close() {
        this.modal.close();
    }

    open() {
        this.modal.open();
    }

}
```

**main.ts:**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.7.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/bundles/ng2-bs3-modal.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to add jquery.js,bootstrap.js,bootstrap.css in to your index.html,  ng2-bs3-modal depends on those scripts.